# Docker Mysql container need to be restared at least one time to be accessible

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a problem with mysql container on docker
the others containers cant connect to mysql after the first "docker-compose up -d"
I always need to restart the mysql container to resolve the problem.

docker-compose code :

```
db_service:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    command: mysqld --sql_mode=""
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - 'db_data:/var/lib/mysql'
        - './conf/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/schema.sql:ro'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysqlrootpwd
        MYSQL_DATABASE: database_1
    ports:
        - '3306:3306'
phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db_service
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '8282:80'
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db_service
```

Any one can help please !

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried adding `#` to the first on `command` lines?

Comment: Why should i add # to the first on command lines?

Comment: I think the problem maybe is with that line, did you try that? Or even are you sure schema file is fine?